# Module not found: Can't resolve, css-loader load the wrong url twice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, css-loader

I'm not sure why my css-loader loads the url twice.

```
/assets/scss/font-awesome/ This repeats twice and it can't get the files.
```

And it becomes this:

```
./assets/scss/font-awesome/assets/fonts/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.eot
```

The original error:

```
./src/index.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--6-oneOf-5-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-4!./src/index.scss)
Module not found: Can't resolve './assets/scss/font-awesome/assets/fonts/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.eot' in '/Users/jaskson/Dropbox/Code/tws/tws_dashboard/dashboard/src'
```

Comment: Looks like you already set baseUrl to the ```/assets/scss``` so it duplicates.

Comment: i was working on this project for awhile and i upgraded a package and this happens. where is the baseurl?

Comment: Will this works for you (with dot) ```./assets/scss/font-awesome/```

Comment: i know this is the baseurl ./assets/scss/font-awesome/ but where do i change it?

Comment: Check your .env file does it have ```PUBLIC_URL``` set?